# Is Moxxi's Good Touch supposed to vibrate?

Tags: borderlands-2, technical-issues

Whenever I freshly switch to Moxxi's Good Touch - e.g.: coming out of a menu with it already equipped, or switching back to it after having used another weapon - my controller starts to vibrate. It doesn't stop vibrating until I fire at least one shot. This is *extremely* annoying, but it doesn't happen with any other gun.

Is this some sort of bug, or is it a known intended feature of this particular gun? Is there any other workaround for it, aside from turning off controller vibration entirely or wasting a bullet every time the vibrations start?

Comment: I suspect that is a feature of that particular "weapon"...

Comment: The Bad Touch, if I remember correctly, vibrates even more...

Comment: Dammit! I'm losing out on happy funtimes by playing with keyboard and mouse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The constant vibration is the primary special effect of that particular gun (though it also has the heal-on-damage all Moxxi-branded weapons get). And no, there is no way to turn it off completely other than simply turning off vibration entirely.

The Wikia wiki on Borderlands has [an entire page](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Weapon_Effects_(Borderlands_2)) about the special effects of various weapons, if you ever need a reference.

Comment: Do the vibrations happen on the PC (if playing on a controller) or Xbox 360 versions too? Because if yes, this question probably has to be edited to remove the [ps3] tag.

Comment: @galacticninja, they do. Also, what PS3 tag?

Answer (score 1):

It a joke, Its Moxxi's Vibrator. "Her favorite gun" ;)